# How to move wordpress/woocommerce website to new host and new domain?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Make a copy of the database, change links in the db.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'old_domain', 'new_domain') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'old_domain', 'new_domain');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE (post_excerpt, 'old_domain', 'new_domain');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'old_domain','new_domain');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE (comment_content, 'old_domain', 'new_domain');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_author_url = REPLACE (comment_author_url, 'old_domain','new_domain');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'old_domain', 'new_domain') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Change wp-config file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'newdomain');
define('WP_HOME', 'newdomain');
```

What else is need to be done ? 
I tested this for localhost and not all the links were updated and got somee minor bugs.

Comment: you can use search & replace plugin

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins save links in the database in the serialized form, like that: `s:46:\"/var/www/test/wp-content/themes/test/style.css\"`
If you make a "REPLACE", then you may encounter the problem of not displaying some data. To avoid any problems, it is better to use plugins. Check: 

[WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/);

[All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/);

[Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest All in one WP [migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/), along with [wppusher](https://wppusher.com/). Then you can take the theme anywhere you want and do as you please

Answer (score 0):

Moving a wordpress/woocommerce website to new host and new domain is pretty simple, you can just install [All In One Wp Migration plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) and if needed you can increase the upload size by going into constants.php file on line no 308 and can replace 2 with 4 or 5.

```
define( 'AI1WM_MAX_FILE_SIZE', 2 << 28 );
```